# How to position fix a button inside a particular div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Button show has `position: fixed` property only inside the second div. When I scroll to the first or last div, button should not be fixed on them, which means the button should be visible only inside the second div, how can I do that?

```css
.one{
                height:600px;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: red;
            }
            .two{
                height:600px;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: yellow;
            }
            .three{
                height:600px;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: pink;
            }
            .mybutton{
                width:80px;
                height: 20px;
                position: fixed;
                right:10px;
                top:100px;
            }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <body>
            <div class="one">                
              <button class="mybutton">Click</button>
            </div>
            <div class="two"></div>
            <div class="three"></div>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Did any of the answers here help solve your question? If so, pls choose one and mark as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way, though I don't know if it's the one you're looking for. Use `position:sticky` on the button, and `position:relative` on the container (`.two`)

```css
.one {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.two {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

.three {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}

.mybutton {
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  position: sticky;
  right: 10px;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"><button class="mybutton">Click</button></div>
<div class="three"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Position: fixed places an element relative to the view port. If you want to place an element relative to a parent element, place it inside the parent element with Position:relative

```
.one{
                height:600px;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: red;
            }
            .two{
                height:600px;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: yellow;
            }
            .three{
                height:600px;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: pink;
            }
            .mybutton{
                width:80px;
                height: 20px;
                position: relative;
                right:10px;
                top:100px;
            }
```

```
<html>
    <head>
        <body>
            <div class="one"></div>
            <div class="two">
               <button class="mybutton">Click</button>
            </div>
            <div class="three"></div>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: you can also try `position:absolute` to act as fixed inside div container.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll

With window.scroll() you can attach event on the scroll of the page like eg:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
     $('.mybutton').css("position": "fixed");
   }else if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200 || $(window).scrollTop() < 100){
     $('.mybutton').css("position": "static");
   }
})`
```